# Right way to discretize continuous piecewise affine differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let's say I have the scalar differential equation
\begin{equation}
\dot x =
\begin{cases}
-x-1 & \text{if} \ x \leq0 \\
x-1  & \text{if} \ x >0 \\
\end{cases},
\end{equation}
which is piecewise affine and continuous $\forall x$.

For a given sampling time $h$, I would like to derive a discrete version of it, in the form
\begin{equation}
x_{k+1} =
\begin{cases}
a_1 x_k + b_1 & \text{if} \ x_k \leq0 \\
a_2 x_k + b_2 & \text{if} \ x_k >0 \\
\end{cases},
\end{equation}
but I would like this discrete time representation to preserve continuity in the origin (i.e., $b_1 = b_2$).

I realized that, among the common discretization schemes, the only method that gives a continuous discretization is forward Euler, that however, has very poor performances when switches do not occur.

What is the right way to discretize this class of differential equations? Is it possible to derive an exact discretization scheme like it can be done for linear ODEs?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "right way to discretize"? Do you want to use the explicit Euler method? In that case, use $x_{i+1} = x_i + hf(x_i)$ where $f$ is the piecewise affine function given above and $h$ is the step width.

Comment: Hi! No, I know how explicit Euler works; with "right way to discretize" I mean a good discretization rule for this kind of equations. In particular, I don't want the discretization scheme to introduce discontinuities that the original $f(x)$ doesn't have! If, for example, I use implicit Euler or RK4 or others, I get a discontinuity of $x_{k+1} (x_k)$ for $x_k = 0$. Thanks!